# How to view a package dependency diagram?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

There are ways to view *module* dependencies, *gradle* dependencies, and even *class* dependencies in various diagrams. A quick google search should turn up these tools.

I have not, however, had any luck finding a way to view *package* dependencies. I simply want a diagram showing how packages depend on each other based on import statements made within their source files. This visualization will be hugely helpful when trying to split a single module into multiple modules.

One response I anticipate is from java developers who may say that *class* dependencies are useful enough. However, I code in Kotlin where package-level members are possible. I have tried a class dependency diagram and it didn't seem to work for analyzing the dependencies of these package-level members. Also, that's unneccesary. All I need is to check the import statements, and I don't need to know where in each file those imported members are used.

Comment: Why standard Java class diagrams are not suitable in your use-case? Like that: https://i.imgur.com/krIXARE.png

Comment: Seems packages could not be shown in the UML diagrams yet, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265033

Comment: Have you tried https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dsm-analysis.html? It shows module/package/files dependency.

Comment: @МихаилНафталь , if I try to do dsm I get various errors. It appears incompatible with gradle. First it tells me there are no class files, and gives me a yes/no choice for whether to build the project up to date (even if I already fully built on gradle). If I select "No", I get an error saying there are no class files. If I say yes, it forces the IDE to try to "build" using its own internal build system. But I only every build with gradle so I don't know anything about the IDE's build system. The IDE build system throws some errors that don't make sense

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov I tried the regular class digrams, and they don't make it possible to visualize package dependencies. Say I have a line of code `val a = someVariable` that is top-level in a kt file and `someVariable` is imported from another kt file in a different package. I don't see any way to visualize this dependency in current diagrams.

Comment: @MattGroth Do you have `Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Build and run using` set to `Gradle`?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь I just checked and yes, Gradle is selected for both "Build and run using" and for "Run tests using"